# add_address_book does not save after closing wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I am trying to work with the `add_address_book`function https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#add_address_book

I have noticed that I can add and get the addresses, but when I close the wallet and daemon and then reopen them, the address book is emtpy.

has anyone ran into this issue?

Comment: Are you really sure you saved the wallet ?

Comment: To add, are you running `monero-wallet-cli` and `monero-wallet-rpc` concurrently with the same wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem. It was because when I close the wallet, I need to issue the stop wallet command before I close the wallet, otherwise the cache is not saved. https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#stop_wallet